# ConnectException (timed out) running groovy Koans with gradle wrapper

Tags: java, windows, groovy, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to run groovy koans http://groovykoans.org/ and when I use the gradlew script it tries to download gradle from the internet (from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip)

But it crashes with a connection timed out exception. I'm able to download the file fine from firefox. I've included http proxy args on the command line as per the instructions and I can ping services.gradle.org from my machine.

I'm on windows.

```
C:\Users\me\My Documents\documents\work\build_system\groovykoans-master>gradlew removeSolutions -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.blah.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

If I can't solve the connect issue is there a way I can manually install the gradle that I've successfully downloaded via my browser and bypass the download step from the gradlewrapper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I managed to work out where the gradle zip was being put (C:\Users\me\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.8-bin\vruqmccc8532n7gr46qavsii8 so I dropped my separately downloaded zip in there and it got me past the issue.

However since then I've also realized I was specifying the -Dhttp properties after the command and not before it so I suspect had I done that it would have worked. (Haven't retried it with a cleaned install area though) i.e I should have had

```
gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.blah.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000 removeSolutions
```

instead of:

```
gradlew removeSolutions -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.blah.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000
```

duh!

Comment: For https use : gradlew.bat -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.blah.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8000 assembleRelease